# Aggregating values of particular key in json array - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-13

I have a table of the similar format :

```
chat_id |                                                                                                                                         agent_details                                                   
---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 chat_1  | [{"agentId": "agent01", "transferFromAgentName": "e2eagent01"}, {"agentId": "nemo-user", "transferFromAgentName": "N/A"}, {"agentId": "salesdemo-nemo-user-e2eagent01", "transferFromAgentName": "e2eagent05"}, {"agentId": "salesdemo-nemo-user-e2eagent01", "transferFromAgentName": "N/A"}]
 chat_1  | [{"agentId": "agent01", "transferFromAgentName": "agent5"}, {"agentId": "nemo-user", "transferFromAgentName": "agent6"}, {"agentId": "salesdemo-nemo-user-e2eagent01", "transferFromAgentName": "N/A"}]
```

I need to extract all the `transferFromAgentName` associated with each `chat_id` in a GROUP BY statement.

I tried the following query, but I'm able to read only the first `transferFromAgentName` from the `agent_details` column.

```
select 
chat_id, 
array_remove(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT agent_details::json->0  ->> 'transferFromAgentName'), 'N/A') 
FROM 
temp.chatsession 
GROUP BY chat_id;
```

which gives the following output :

```
chat_id |    array_remove
---------+---------------------
 chat_1  | {agent5,e2eagent01}
```

I require all `transferFromAgentName` to be present in the second column, i.e. `{e2eagent01,e2eagent05,agent5,agent6}`

*CREATE AND INSERT QUERIES :*

```
CREATE TABLE chatsession (
  chat_id varchar(20),
  agent_details JSONB
);

INSERT INTO chatsession
VALUES ('chat_1', '[
    {
        "agentId": "agent01",
        "transferFromAgentName": "e2eagent01"
    },
    {
        "agentId": "nemo-user",
        "transferFromAgentName": "N/A"
    },
    {
        "agentId": "salesdemo-nemo-user-e2eagent01",
        "transferFromAgentName": "e2eagent05"
    },
    {
        "agentId": "salesdemo-nemo-user-e2eagent01",
        "transferFromAgentName": "N/A"
    }
]'),
('chat_1', '[
    {
        "agentId": "agent01",
        "transferFromAgentName": "agent5"
    },
    {
        "agentId": "nemo-user",
        "transferFromAgentName": "agent6"
    },
    {
        "agentId": "salesdemo-nemo-user-e2eagent01",
        "transferFromAgentName": "N/A"
    }
]');
```

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: `SELECT version()` returns `PostgreSQL 13.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit`

Comment: So you want `{e2eagent01,N/A,e2eagent05,N/A,agent5,agent6,N/A}` as the result?

Comment: Yes, the same with all the `N/A` removed. So `{e2eagent01,e2eagent05,agent5,agent6}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unnest the array before you can aggregate the elements from different rows.

```
select c.chat_id, 
       array_agg(d.item ->> 'transferFromAgentName')
from chatsession c
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(c.agent_details) as d(item)
where d.item ->> 'transferFromAgentName' <> 'N/A'  
group by c.chat_id
```